# Hazelcast: How to enable declarative Configuration correctly

Tags: hazelcast

I have a running programatical configuration in my class, that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class HazelCastConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Config config()
    {
        NetworkConfig networkConfig = new NetworkConfig();
        networkConfig.setPublicAddress("localhost").addOutboundPort(5701);
        
        EvictionConfig evictionConfig = new EvictionConfig();
        evictionConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);
        evictionConfig.setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.PER_NODE);
        evictionConfig.setSize(120000);
        
        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
        mapConfig.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(0);
        mapConfig.setMaxIdleSeconds(0);
        mapConfig.setEvictionConfig(evictionConfig);
        mapConfig.setName("default");
        
        SerializationConfig serializationConfig = new SerializationConfig();
        serializationConfig.addDataSerializableFactoryClass(MachineDataSerializableFactory.FACTORY_ID, MachineDataSerializableFactory.class);
        
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setNetworkConfig(networkConfig);
        config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
        config.setSerializationConfig(serializationConfig);
    
        return config;
    }
}
```

But when I try to extract the "evictionConfig" and the "serializationConfig" into a hazelcast.yml, located in "src/ressources" - it does not work anymore. That means, when I check the mapConfig within HazelcastManagementCenter, the "evictionConfig" i.e. is not applied.

That is my YML-file:

```
# hazelcast.yaml
hazelcast:
  group:
     name: 'dev'
     management-center:
      enabled: true
      url: 'http://hazelcast-mgmt:8080/hazelcast-mancenter'
     network:
      port:
       port: 5701
      join:
       multicast:
        enabled: false
       tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
        - 127.0.0.1:5701
     map:
       default:
         eviction:
           eviction-policy: LRU
           max-size-policy: PER_NODE
           size: 120000
     serialization:
       data-serializable-factories:
         - factory-id: 1000
           class-name: com.company.software.caching.MachineDataSerializableFactory
```

Regards and Thx for any help

Comment: I solved this by removing the HazelCastConfigClass completely (deleting the file). Hazelcast searches for a class with Config first, followed by xml and then yaml in the classpath. After that my yaml gets applied.

Answer (score 0):

Map eviction is set on particular map, in your case it is default map. Is is present in your yaml.
There is nothing wrong, the configuration yaml contains that information.

```
map:
       default:
         eviction:
           eviction-policy: LRU
           max-size-policy: PER_NODE
           size: 120000
```

Go through below link

https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map.html#configuring-map-eviction